# C# Unit Test: Ignore branches in nested method during branch code coverage check. NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, code-coverage

I am testing my `C#` code with `NUnit` and check the branch code coverage. One of the classes uses a service (`_dbService`) which is a wrapper around DB related classes (Connection, Command, Data Reader and etc.). This class has a method (`Query`) which receives SQL command, a mapper function and a collection of parameters. I validate the query and the mapper outside the unit tests using an integration test. Therefore, I like to skip the branches caused by the mapper. The following are the class and it's tests.

The class

```cs
internal sealed class TheClassService : ITheClassService
{
    private readonly IDbService _dbService;

    public TheClassService(IDbService dbService)
    {
        _dbService = dbService;
    }

    async Task<UserModel> ITheClassService.Get(int id)
    {
        var enumerable = await _dbService.Query(
            GetQueryString("WHERE u.id = " + id),
            MapToUserModel);

        return enumerable.Single();
    }

    async Task<UserModel?> IUserService.Find(string phoneNumber)
    {
        var enumerable = await _dbService.Query(
            GetQueryString("WHERE phonenumber = @phonenumber LIMIT 1"),
            MapToUserModel,
            _dbService.CreateParameter("phonenumber", phoneNumber)
            );

        return enumerable.SingleOrDefault();
    }

    private static string GetQueryString(string whereClause)
    {
        return "Main part of command" +
            whereClause;
    }

    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    private static Model MapToUserModel(System.Data.IDataReader reader)
    {
        return new Model
            (
                reader.GetInt32(0),
                reader.GetString(1),
                reader.GetString(2),
                reader.IsDBNull(3) ? null
                    : new(
                        reader.GetInt32(3),
                        reader.GetString(4),
                        reader.GetNullableDecimal(5))
            );
    }
}
```

The tests

```cs
public sealed class  TheClassServiceTests
{
    public void Get_throws_when_id_is_invalid()
    {
        var dbService = new Mock<IDbService>();

        dbService
            .Setup(x => x.Query(
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<Func<IDataReader, Model>>(),
                It.IsAny<IDataParameter[]>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(Enumerable.Empty<Model>());

        ITheClassService service = new TheClassService(dbService.Object);

        Assert.That(() => service.Get(1), Throws.Exception);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task Get_returns_for_valid_id()
    {
        var dbService = new Mock<IDbService>();

        dbService
            .Setup(x => x.Query(
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<Func<IDataReader, Model>>(),
                It.IsAny<IDataParameter[]>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(new Model[] { new(1, "t", "n") });

        ITheClassService service = new TheClassService(dbService.Object);

        var actual = await service.Get(1);

        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(new Model(1, "t", "n")));
    }

    [TestCase(0)]
    [TestCase(1)]
    public async Task Find_does_not_throw_for_any_number_of_rows(int rowCount)
    {
        var queryResult = new List<Model>();

        for (int counter = 0; counter < rowCount; counter++)
            queryResult.Add(new(1, "t", "n"));

        var dbService = new Mock<IDbService>();

        dbService
            .Setup(x => x.Query(
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<Func<IDataReader, Model>>(),
                It.IsAny<IDataParameter[]>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(queryResult);

        ITheClassService service = new TheClassService(dbService.Object);

        var actual = await service.Find("n");

        if (rowCount == 0)
            Assert.That(actual, Is.Null);
        else
            Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(new UserModel(1, "t", "n")));
    }
}
```

As you can see, both `Get` and `Find` methods are quick similar. And both are tested for the time that query results in and empty and non-empty collections. However, test tools suggest that only 3 of 4 branches here are tested.

Based on the different setup I have done, the branch is the `MapToUserModel` method which is excluded from code coverage.

Do you know why `Find` is fully tested, but `Get` is partially tested?

Comment: Have you tried using `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` on those methods or the whole class?

Comment: Actually I don't like to exclude them as there are some logic in them. This is a minimized version of the code but the removed logics has no branch.